# Custom Reading Function for FFMPEG I/O

Tags: c++, c, audio, casting, ffmpeg

I need to create a custom reading callback function that can read contents of a file in the form of a  `std::string` into a `uint8_t * buf`. I tried multiple different methods found around the internet and on stackoverflow but sometimes it works and other the the program infinitely loops or stops execution half way.

I have no problems with amr/3gp files but all wav/pcm files are causing some problems for some reason. All I know its something to do with the reading function I have so far.

Ideally I would like to be able to give the program any type of file and then it converts it.

This is how I am calling the `readCallback` function from the code:

```
//create the buffer
uint8_t * avio_ctx_buffer = NULL;

//allocate space for the buffer using ffmpeg allocation method
avio_ctx_buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);

//Allocate and initialize an AVIOContext for buffered I/O.
//audio variable contains the contents of the audio file
avio_ctx = avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size,0, &audio, &readCallback, NULL, NULL);
```

Here is the callback function that works on some types of files:

```
static int readCallback(void* opaque, uint8_t * buf, int buf_size){  
  std::string * file =static_cast<std::string *>(opaque);
  if(file->length() == 0){
   return AVERROR_EOF; //if we reach to the end of the string, return
                       // return End of file
  }

  // Creating a vector of the string size
  std::vector<uint8_t> array(file->length());

  //Copying the contents of the string into the vector
  std::copy(file->begin(),file->end(),array.begin());

  //Copying the vector into buf
  std::copy(array.begin(),array.end(),buf);


  return file->length();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After tyring some stuff for awhile, I got a solution using std::stringstream and it works well with several formats I tested with so far: 3gp/amr,wav/pcm,mp3.

Here a the snippet of code:

```
//Create a string stream that contains the audio
std::stringstream audio_stream(audio);

//create the buffer
uint8_t * avio_ctx_buffer = NULL;

//allocate space for the buffer using ffmpeg allocation method
avio_ctx_buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);


//Allocate and initialize an AVIOContext for buffered I/O.
//Pass the stringstream audio_stream
avio_ctx = avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size,0,&audio_stream, &readCallback, NULL, NULL);
```

The callback function:

```
static int readFunction1(void* opaque, uint8_t * buf, int buf_size){
   //Cast the opaque pointer to std::stringstream
   std::stringstream * me =static_cast<std::stringstream *>(opaque);

   //If we are at the end of the stream return FFmpeg's EOF
   if(me->tellg() == buf_size){
     return AVERROR_EOF;
   }
   // Read the stream into the buf and cast it to char *
   me->read((char*)buf, buf_size);

   //return how many characters extracted
   return me->tellg();
}
```